# Data entered in product java class is giving exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, javabeans

Hi I am getting the following Exception in the springMVC application code.. I read some previous question but didn't find any help.

I have two entities in the application i.e.

- user
- products

Data entered in product java class is giving exception:-

> exception 
>   org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.onlineshopping.model.Product
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:659)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

Product.java class is :

```
package com.onlineshopping.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Product")
public class Product implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name="productid")
        private Integer proid;

        @Column(name="productname")
        private String proname;


        @Column(name="price")
        private Integer price;


        @Column(name="details")
        private String details;

        public Integer getProid() {
            return proid;
        }

        public void setProid(Integer proid) {
            this.proid = proid;
        }

        public String getProname() {
            return proname;
        }

        public void setProname(String proname) {
            this.proname = proname;
        }

        public Integer getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        public void setPrice(Integer price) {
            this.price = price;
        }

        public String getDetails() {
            return details;
        }

        public void setDetails(String details) {
            this.details = details;
        }
    }
```

Configuration File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/database.properties" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.onlineshopping" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.onlineshopping.model.Customer</value>
            </list>
        </property> 
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>             
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Can someone tell me why this exception occur.the other user entity is working correctly.
thanks

Comment: session factory needs models so component scan needs there anyway you just adding Customer what about adding product also ? <list>
                <value>com.onlineshopping.model.Customer</value> <value> ...product</value>
            </list>

Comment: @mithat konuk Thanks it is working .. please paste it as the answer so that i can upvote and accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so after comment @dhs found answer

session factory needs to setPackagesToScan so do try this adding into annotatedClasses
**com.onlineshopping.model.Product**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/database.properties" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.onlineshopping" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.onlineshopping.model.Customer</value>
                <value>com.onlineshopping.model.Product</value>
            </list>
        </property> 
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>             
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Ha ha ha Thanks for the answer